# Previous page not loading after clicking browser back button after a page redirection

Tags: javascript, c#

From a sign up success thanks page I am redirecting to another webpage using window.location object. But after redirecting, clicking browser back button shows the sign up page not the sign up success thanks page. Tried the same scenario without pressing the back button instead used window.history.go(-1) , this works fine it loads the success thanks page itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href = 'YOUR LINK'`

Right now, you are replacing the current page url (success page) with the new page (redirected page), so when you go back you go to the previous page in the history stack, which is the sign up page.

You can also use [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) to add entries to the location history

Comment: Tried using window.location.href but still having the same issue.

Comment: update your question with your code @SharonKumar